# Can I use a cell reference in another tab from a query select statement?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have two tabs in a google sheet. Tab A and Tab B

From Tab A, I am using the following statement in a cell:

`=iferror(query('TabB'!$A$2:$H$50000,"select sum(E) where G = 'name@emailaddy.com' label sum(E) ''",0))`

THIS WORKS

I want to make the name@emailaddy.com dynamic so it pulls from a cell in Tab A

`ex. =iferror(query('TabB'!$A$2:$H$50000,CONCATENATE("(select sum(E) where G = ","'name@emailaddy.com'"," label sum(E) ''",0)))`

DOES NOT WORK - I just get a blank field

I have tried to simply aggregate the strings with "+" signs as well that does not work.

How can I achieve the result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb. Figured it out.

`=query('TabB'!$A$2:$H$50000,"select sum(E) where G = '" & TABA!E4 & "' label sum(E) ''",0)`